# Radio button array post

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am developing an exam form using PHP. When I add an option, it also have a radio button to check if it is a correct answer. So for multiple options there will radio buttons for each of them - I want to insert these into the database.

So, if the radio button is checked it passes post value 'Yes' and if it is unchecked passes 'No' value. When checking a radio button, I give it a value 'correct' and for the others, empty value. All radio buttons have the same name. It is an array named 'correct[]'.

When submitting form, I fetch the radio buttons using a for loop. My code is below:

```php
for($x=0;$x<=10;$x++){
     $correct = $_POST['correct'][$x]
     
     if($correct == 'correct'){
         $is_correct = "Yes";
     }else{
         $is_correct = "No";
     }
}
```

but, I got my first option Yes, but for all others no

Comment: if all radio inputs have same name, then **only one** of them can be checked. try using checkboxes insted.

Comment: Would be helpful to see your form as well

Answer (score 0):

You should try input type checkbox not radio button for multi select.

```
  <input value="yes" type="checkbox" name="correct[]" />
```